# ¿Cómo hacer un pop-up cuando se hace clic en una línea de un dato?

Tags: python, python-3.x, popup, plotly, dash

Tengo un datatable y me gustaría crear un pop-up como un [dash bootstrap Modal](https://dash-bootstrap-components.opensource.faculty.ai/docs/components/modal/) al hacer clic en él:

El código original, en `sto.py` es:

```
import dash_table
import os
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from ..server import app

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATA_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../data/')
df = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH + 'tickers_september_2017_red.csv')


def layout():
    return html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
            data=df.to_dict('records'),
        ),
        dbc.Modal(
            [
                dbc.ModalHeader("Header"),
                dbc.ModalBody("This is the content of the modal"),
                dbc.ModalFooter(
                    dbc.Button("Close", id="close", className="ml-auto")
                ),
            ],
            id="modal",
        )
    ])


@app.callback(Output('modal', 'is_open'),
              [Input('table', 'active_cell'),
               Input('close', 'n_clicks')],
              [State("modal", "is_open")])
def toggle_modal(n1, n2, is_open):
    print("n1: ", n1, " n2: ", n2)
    if n1 or n2:
        return not is_open
    return is_open
```

Pero solo me da la modal por debajo de la tabla. No como una pop-up como en la documentacion.

Entonces intenté

```
import dash_table
import os
import pandas as pd
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output, State
import dash_html_components as html
import dash_bootstrap_components as dbc

from ..server import app

PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.dirname(__file__))
DATA_PATH = os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, '../data/')
df = pd.read_csv(DATA_PATH + 'tickers_september_2017_red.csv')


def layout():
    return html.Div([
        dash_table.DataTable(
            id='table',
            columns=[{"name": i, "id": i} for i in df.columns],
            data=df.to_dict('records'),
        ),
        dbc.Modal(
            [
                dbc.ModalHeader("Header"),
                dbc.ModalBody("This is the content of the modal"),
                dbc.ModalFooter(
                    dbc.Button("Close", id="close", className="ml-auto")
                ),
            ],
            id="modal",
        )
    ])


@app.callback(Output('modal', 'children'),
              [Input('table', 'active_cell'),
               Input('close', 'n_clicks')],
              # [State('modal', 'is_open')]
              )
def update_graph(active_cell, n_clicks):
    print("active_cell: ", active_cell)
    if active_cell is not None:
        row = df.iloc[[active_cell.get("row")]]
        return dbc.Modal(
            [
                dbc.ModalHeader(row['Name'].values[0]),
                dbc.ModalBody("This will be something more interesting"),
                dbc.ModalFooter(
                    dbc.Button("Close", id="close", className="ml-auto")
                ),
            ],
            id="modal",
        )
```

Pero `active_cell` queda como `None`.

Answer (score 0):

debes colocar establecer el valor de @app.layout antes de definir el @app.callback.

prueba colocar `@app.layout = layout` (tu función layout) antes de `@app.callback`

Saludos,

Comment: Muchas gracias para tu respuesta. Intenté prueba colocar `@app.layout = layout()` (mi función layout) antes de @app.callback, moviendo la función y la @ antes de la función de actualización. pero obtengo: `@app.layout = layout()
SyntaxError: invalid syntax`. Tal vez no tomé tu consejo muy bien. Espero que estas bien cualquier donde sea.

Comment: Hola, 

Entendido, hazlo sin el '@', se me paso ese detalle de tu pregunta.

Comment: En efecto, con `from ..server import app` no hay el error. Pero todavía no me permite hacer un pop-up. Puesto al dia mi pregunta